# VB.NET stream read calculate crc32

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter, crc32

I am reading files using stream reader and writer with a buffer. Is it possible to calculate the crc32 checksum of the file at the same time so that it would evaluate the buffer during each iteration, and the result would be the crc32 of the complete file, instead of having to read teh file twice? Here is the code:

```
   Public Function APPEND_FILE_TO_FILE(ByVal SOURCE_FILE As String, ByVal DESTINATION_FILE As String)
        Dim nn As New FileInfo(SOURCE_FILE)
        Dim BUFFER(BUFFER_SIZE) As Byte
        Dim BYTES_READ As Long = 0
        Using inFile As New System.IO.FileStream(SOURCE_FILE, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
            Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream(DESTINATION_FILE, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Write)
                Do
                    BYTES_READ = inFile.Read(BUFFER, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)
                    TOTAL_PROCESSED_DATA += BYTES_READ ' GUI related
                    outFile.Write(BUFFER, 0, BYTES_READ)
                Loop While BYTES_READ > 0
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

CRC32 function:

```
Public Function GetCRC32(ByVal sFileName As String) As String
    Try
        Dim FS As FileStream = New FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)
        Dim CRC32Result As Integer = &HFFFFFFFF
        Dim Buffer(4096) As Byte
        Dim ReadSize As Integer = 4096
        Dim Count As Integer = FS.Read(Buffer, 0, ReadSize)
        Dim CRC32Table(256) As Integer
        Dim DWPolynomial As Integer = &HEDB88320
        Dim DWCRC As Integer
        Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer
        'Create CRC32 Table
        For i = 0 To 255
            DWCRC = i
            For j = 8 To 1 Step -1
                If (DWCRC And 1) Then
                    DWCRC = ((DWCRC And &HFFFFFFFE) \ 2&) And &H7FFFFFFF
                    DWCRC = DWCRC Xor DWPolynomial
                Else
                    DWCRC = ((DWCRC And &HFFFFFFFE) \ 2&) And &H7FFFFFFF
                End If
            Next j
            CRC32Table(i) = DWCRC
        Next i
        'Calcualting CRC32 Hash
        Do While (Count > 0)
            For i = 0 To Count - 1
                n = (CRC32Result And &HFF) Xor Buffer(i)
                CRC32Result = ((CRC32Result And &HFFFFFF00) \ &H100) And &HFFFFFF
                CRC32Result = CRC32Result Xor CRC32Table(n)
            Next i
            Count = FS.Read(Buffer, 0, ReadSize)
        Loop
        Return Hex(Not (CRC32Result))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: "i would like to..." is not a question.  Where are we to start?  Do you have a CRC algortihm?  Why CRC rather than one of several hash methods already in .NET?  please calify

Comment: It is a question. "How does one calculate the crc checksum of a file while in a streamreader loop?" Why crc32? crc32 seams good to check file integrity during file transfer while still being light. There is no need for a cryptographic hash function either. Yes, I do have a crc32 function, however, would it not be faster to do the calculation and writing at the same time, instead of having to read the file twice?

Comment: yes it is possible to calculate the CRC of a stream on the fly, but not with that code.  You'd need to modify it to accept the CRC so far for each block of bytes.  A SHA hash would be more reliable.

Comment: Just rewrite your CRC32 method to take a Byte() instead of a filename.  With a separate Initialize() method.  Very little point to this btw, disk drives and network cards already use a CRC check.

Comment: @Hans Passant Yes, I did think about making it accept a byte array, but I am uncertain as to what to do with the result. I would somehow need to accumulate the crc result until all the data has been read through so that the result of the crc is the entire file. The reason i need to do this with a stream is because it will be impractical to load all the data of the file in memory... I intend to store the crc for later reference.

Answer (score 0):

The above code leaves the file being parsed [open] and cannot be renamed or deleted.
The line:
Count = FS.Read(Buffer, 0, ReadSize)
Loop
Return Hex(Not (CRC32Result))
Should Be:
Count = FS.Read(Buffer, 0, ReadSize)
Loop
FS.Close
Return Hex(Not (CRC32Result))

Then the file can be manipulated again.